# Nightwatch.js Unable to extract text of from an element using CSS or xpath on http://google.com

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, nightwatch.js

I am trying to get the text from an element for one of our projects using Nightwatch.js. In the example I tried to Extract the "About" Text from Google using CSS and later xpath, but in any case I got the following error message "ERROR: Unable to locate element: "About" using: xpath"

My code is :

```
> /* jshint expr: true */ module.exports = {   tags: ['google'],   'Demo
> test Google' : function (client) {
>     client
>       .url('http://google.com')
>       .pause(1000);
>     client.useXpath();
>     // var C ='#hptl > a:nth-child(1)'
>     var C = '//*[@id="hptl"]/a[1]'
>     client.waitForElementVisible(C, 3000);
>     // var B = client.getText(C)
>     var nestedValue;
> 
>     client.getText(C, function(result) {
>     var value = result.value;
>     client.getText(value, function(result) {
>         nestedValue = result.value; 
>     }); }); console.log(nestedValue);
>     client.end();   } };
```

The output is :

```
> Running:  Demo test Google undefined  √ Element <//*[@id="hptl"]/a[1]>
> was visible after 61 milliseconds. ERROR: Unable to locate element:
> "About" using: xpath
>     at Object.<anonymous> (
```

Comment: That's not CSS... that's an XPath.

Comment: @JeffC, yes, that's why I added the .useXpath() function. you may also notice that I have commented out the line  // var CSS ='#hptl > a:nth-child(1)' just to test if xpath works here. neither css or xpath worked for me

Comment: It's confusing that you are using an XPath in a variable named `CSS`.

Comment: Use this XPath: `//a[.='About']`

Comment: Thanks. I have also changed the variable "CSS" to C so that the confusion can be avoiided

Comment: You should strive to use descriptive variable names... C, while less confusing than CSS, isn't descriptive at all.

Answer (score 0):

To locate the element with text as **About** on the webpage `https://www.google.com/` you can use either of the following solutions:

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  a.Fx4vi[href*='about']
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  //a[text()='About']
  ```